# Смысл O-нотации

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Помогите разобраться с *O*-нотацией. Насколько я понял:

- *O(h(n))* означает, что алгоритм ведет себя в **наихудшем** случает как *c*h(n)*, начиная с какой-то величины *n<sub>0</sub>*, где *c* — константа.
- *Ω(h(n))* означает, что алгоритм ведет себя в **наилучшем** случае как
  *c*h(n)*, начиная с какой-то величины *n<sub>0</sub>*, где *c* — константа.
- *ο(h(n))* означает, что алгоритм ведет себя в **наихудшем** случае
  **«асимптотически лучше»**, чем *c*h(n)*, начиная с какой-то величины *n<sub>0</sub>*, где *c* — константа.
- *ω(h(n))* означает, что алгоритм ведет себя в **наилучшем** случае
  **«асимптотически хуже»**, чем *c*h(n)*, начиная с какой-то величины *n<sub>0</sub>*, где *c* — константа.

Не могу понять что означает *Θ(h(n))*, поясните пожалуйста. И если я ошибся в предыдущих определениях, поправьте пожалуйста.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation?rq=1 может кто переведет

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Смотрите. Пусть `f(n)` — количество шагов алгоритма.

Сложность `O(h(n))` означает, что алгоритм требует количества шагов, не большего, чем `h(n)`, умноженное на какую-то константу. То есть, `lim f(n)/h(n)` при растущем `n` конечен.

Так вот, говорят, что `f(n) = Θ(h(n))`, если `f(n) = O(h(n))` и одновременно `h(n) = O(f(n))`. Это значит, что функции `f(n)` и `h(n)` имеют как бы одинаковый порядок роста.

---

Пример: если настоящая сложность алгоритма `f(n) = 2n^2 + 30n + log(n^4)`, то `f(n) = O(n^2)`, т. к. `2n^2 + 30n + log(n^4) / n^2 = 2 + 30/n + 4 log n/n^2 -> 2` при бесконечно растущем `n`.

Но одновременно `f(n) = O(n^100)`. Действительно, `2n^2 + 30n + log(n^4) / n^100 = 2/n^98 + 30/n^99 + 4 log n/n^100 -> 0` при бесконечно растущем `n`. Видите? То есть, `O(h(n))` есть как бы лишь верхняя оценка сложности алгоритма, как угодно грубая.

Далее: `f(n) = Θ(n^2)`. Действительно, `f(n) / h(n) -> 2` (как мы уже выясняли), а `h(n) / f(n)` очевидно стремится к 0.5.

С другой стороны, `f(n) ≠ Θ(n^100)`, потому что `n^100 / (2n^2 + 30n + log(n^4)) = n^98 * (n^2) / (2n^2 + 30n + log(n^4)) = n^98 * (1 / (2 + 30/n + 4 log n / n))`, а этот предел расходится, т. к. знаменатель ограничен, а `n^98` стремится к бесконечности.

---

Таким образом, `Θ` является более *точной* оценкой сложности алгоритма.

---

Примечание для математиков-пуристов: да, предел не обязательно существует, строго говоря, нужен `lim sup`.

Comment: выходит что разница между O(h(n)) и ο(h(n)) в том что ο(h(n)) всегда грубая "оценка сверху" а O(h(n)) может совпадать с "точной" ?

Comment: @SergeyNikolaev: Так и есть, да.